# Deserialize LiveSDK calendar with JSon.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I am new to JSon, especially JSon.Net. I am trying to use the LiveSDK on Windows Phone and i am having an issue parsing out the JSon response. I am trying to read calendar information and   I can't get it to parse.  Below is my code for downloading the Json and my class definition. I get an exception on the line defining 'user'.

```
    void getCal_DownloadCompleted(object sender, LiveDownloadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
            {
                var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Calendar>(json);
            }
        }
    }
```

My Calendar class

```
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Calendar
{    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="name")]
    public string Name{get; set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id{get; set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
    public string Description{get; set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "created_time")]
    public string CreatedTime{get; set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "updated_time")]
    public string UpdatedTime{get; set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "from")]
    public object From{get; set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "is_default")]
    public bool IsDefault{get; set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "subscription_location")]
    public string SubscriptionLocation{get; set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "permissions")]
    public string Permissions{get; set;}
}
```

The JSon Format received

```
    {
    "data": [
  {
     "id": "calendar.42d4dbc866f94c83849c88c6eb9985bc", 
     "name": "Birthday calendar", 
     "description": "If you have birthdays listed for your contacts, they'll appear on this calendar. You can add more birthdays, but you can't add other types of events.", 
     "created_time": "2011-08-05T19:41:04+0000", 
     "updated_time": "2011-08-05T19:41:04+0000", 
     "from": {
        "name": null, 
        "id": null
     }, 
     "is_default": false, 
     "subscription_location": null, 
     "permissions": "read"
  },{
     ...
  }
```

]
}

I was no having luck using the LiveSDK GetAsync() so i went with DownloadAsync() instead. Is this approach better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your serialization class doesn't seem to match the JSON.  JSON is returning an object with one property called `data` that is an array containing elements with the `Calendar` class you defined.

Try adding a new class like:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class AppointmentList
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="data")]
    public List<Calendar> data {get; set;}
}
```

and deserialize like:

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppointmentList>(json);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks very much. I swore i had tried that and it didn't work, but all is well now.